# Multithreaded Java JNI application: does the C++ side act as a single threaded application?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-native-interface

Given a Solver written in C++, and a java class which loads a solver instance through JNI:

```
SolverLoader loader=SolverLoader.getInstance();

Solver solver=loader.getNewSolver();
solver.solve(...);
```

SolverLoader is a singleton class which loads and returns an instance of a Solver on request. It’s essentially an object factory. Each time the getNewSolver() function is invoked, the SolverLoader creates a new instance of a solver on the C++ side through JNI and passes a handle to this instance back to the java side. This is convenient because this allows me to have multiple solvers on the java side: each java side solver maintains a handle to a unique solver instance on the C++ side.

So in short, I can do this:

Solver solver1=loader.getNewSolver();
solver1.solve(...);

Solver solver2=loader.getNewSolver();
solver2.solve(...);

Each of these solvers have totally separated data structures as there's no overlap between the C++ solver instances.

Now what I would like to do is invoke "`solver1.solve(...)`" and "`solver2.solve(...)`" in parallel, i.e. start them in separate java threads. I'm wondering whether this works as expected on the C++ side as well. Should I do something with the multiple threads on the C++ side? I'm worried that even though on the Java side everything is multithreaded, on the C++ side it will act like a single threaded application where solver1 is paused when solver2 is active and vice versa?

Comment: Why would it work like a single threaded application on C++ side, once you're running your C++ code with Java there's only Java side and only Java Threads. It should work as you expect it to work as there would be no C++ context, that's behind the JVM. C++ code is just data or you can even compare it to a compiled class file.

Comment: Not sure why you talk about instances "on the C++ side" or "on the Java side".  There's C++ _code_, and there's Java _code_, but the instances are just instances:  They live on the Java heap, and they can be directly accessed by Java code, or accessed through the JNI by the C++ code.

Comment: When Java code calls a native method, there's no inter-thread communication:  It's just a method call.  Like any other method call, it all stays on the same stack, in the same thread.

Comment: The Java code is multithreaded. The Java code calls the JNI code calls the C++ code, which is therefore also multithreaded. Impossible to see why you would think otherwise.